# Funny TCS-related papers etc?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

What is the funniest TCS-related published work you know?

Please include only those that are intended to be funny.  Works which are explicitly crafted to be intelligently humorous (rather than, say, a published collection of short jokes regarding complexity theory) are preferred.  Works with humorous (actually humorous, not just cute) titles are also accepted.

Please only one work per answer so the "best" ones can bubble to the top.

Comment: what about papers with funny titles ? or should that be a different question ?

Comment: I think funny titles are fine :).

Comment: Why just complexity (and not other TCS topics)? What about books? (I would like to post Concrete Mathematics :) )

Comment: @Kaveh: I didn't mean to be so specific, and have broadened the question accordingly.  By all means, post away!

Comment: there was a paper that investigated the alphabetical ordering of authors in theory conferences: I wish I remember what it was

Comment: for some reason, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles is a closely-related thread.

Comment: I saw a few in the FUN proceedings, e.g. http://fun2010.dia.unisa.it/accepted.html

Comment: @Suresh: I believe you mean http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/1003.6064v1

Comment: @Radu no not that one. THis was written by TCS folk, with an explicit plea to Avi Wigderson to join on and contribute a W :)

Comment: @Suresh: on a related note: http://www.phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=562 :-)

Comment: like the general idea but imho if papers merely with humorous or cute titles are included, which are numerous, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 76):

Scott Aaronson's newspiece: [Polynomial
hierarchy collapses: thousands feared tractable](http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/phcollapse.pdf)

Comment: Hilarious.  I had not seen that before.

Comment: A related tragic (or funny?) headline: [THE SKY IS FALLING (The Strong Exponential Hierarchy Collapses)](http://hdl.handle.net/1813/6617), a technical report by L. Hemachandra. The following footnote is attached to the title: "Chicken Little thought that the sky was falling. It was not."

Answer (score 53):

[The Toilet Paper Problem](http://web.archive.org/web/20120517205020/http://gi.cebitec.uni-bielefeld.de/teaching/2007summer/jclub/papers/toiletPaper.pdf) (Donald Knuth, American Mathematical Monthly, 1984). From the introduction:

> The toilet paper dispensers in a certain building are designed to hold two rolls
> of tissues, and a person can use either roll. There are two kinds of people who use the rest rooms in the building: big-choosers and little-choosers. A big-chooser always takes a piece of toilet paper from the roll that is currently larger; a little-chooser always does the opposite. However, when the two rolls are the same size, or when only one roll is nonempty, everybody chooses the nearest nonempty roll. When both rolls are empty, everybody has a problem.

Comment: Oh, no.  Knuth beat me to it.  I had considered a related, admittedly simpler question and convinced myself that everyone should be a little-chooser to minimize the risk cooperatively (and I have been one since then).  I have never had time to write up the result, though.  At least, I am glad to know the prior work before I write it up and submit it to the International Conference on Theoretical Restrooms.

Comment: There have been semi-rigorous looks at the urinal selection problem from an algorithms POV: http://blog.xkcd.com/2009/09/02/urinal-protocol-vulnerability/

Answer (score 40):

Kyle Burke and David Charlton. [Lower bounds for probably-istic polynomial time.](http://web.archive.org/web/20080211140314/http://cs-people.bu.edu/charlton/probpt.pdf)  Boston University, 2005.  (Thanks to @arnab and the Web Archive for the link.)

I'm pretty sure this was an April Fool's paper, but either way it is *absolutely* hilarious.
The abstract:

> We fill a gap in existing complexity theory by introducing the class of probablyistic
>   polynomial time computations, that is, computations that, you know, probably
>   terminate in polynomial time, as far as we know. We apply this class to show that
>   algorithms for NP-complete problems probably don't run in polynomial time.

Comment: Got it!  I can't find it linked from any existing webpage, but you can retrieve it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20080211140314/http://cs-people.bu.edu/charlton/probpt.pdf

Comment: I was in a class with David Charlton in 2002 when he was an undergraduate so I am pretty sure that must be 2005 not 1995 ;-)

Comment: David wrote this as a hilarious response to a comment I made in grad school.  I don't remember my exact comment, but the paper is hilarious! :-D  I can't take any actual credit for the hilarity.

Answer (score 32):

Andrew W. Appel's "[Is POPL Mathematics or Science?](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/science.pdf)"

This paper studies varies CS conferences and tries to classify them as theoretical or applied based on whether authors order their names in alphabetical order (theoretical) or by  contribution (applied).

Comment: I love the ending "The goal of the research presented in this report was to provide some laughs at POPL ’92; I am happy to say that in this respect the research was entirely successful."

Comment: I would love to see this continued to the present day

Answer (score 26):

Several of [Jean-Yves Girard](http://girard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/)'s papers.

His [Linear Logic](http://girard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/linear.pdf) paper has the following footnote by the editor of Theoretical Computer Science journal:

> Because of its length and novelty this paper has not been subjected to the normal process of refereeing. The editor is prepared to share with the author any criticism that eventually will be expressed concerning this work.

Another one is [Locus Solum, From the rules of logic to the logic of rules](http://girard.perso.math.cnrs.fr/0.pdf). The 192 page paper has an appendix which is almost 100 pages long named "**A pure waste of paper**", the funniest appendix I have ever seen.

Comment: The fantastically odd thing is that "A pure waste of paper" is really very good. You can't naively trust anything he writes in it, but nevertheless there's a serious point about logic hidden within almost every joke/insult/aside.

Comment: French speaking readers may enjoy his paper on [mustard clocks](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~girard/moutarde.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately the third link is broken

Comment: @gallais: Actually, the original version of the "Mustard watches" paper is in english and can be found [here](http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~girard/mustard/article.html).

Comment: This is the "fix" for the link in the main answer: http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~girard/0.pdf

Answer (score 24):

- [The Complexity of Songs](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358027.358042) by Don Knuth
- [On Superpolynomial Subexponential Functions](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=993138) by Alan T. Sherman (not "Man T. Sherman" as the ACM Digital Library suggests).

Comment: Could you split this into two answers?

Comment: Do you mean “superpolylogarithmic”?

Answer (score 22):

The paper by Yonatan Bilu, Dana Porrat and Yoav Yaffe "[On The Number of Condoms at a Cheap Safe-Sex Orgy](http://barkai-serv.weizmann.ac.il/Yonatan/papers/orgy.ps)". This paper was not published, so it doesn't correspond to one of the requirements (to be published work). But I think it can be included here as an exception.

Comment: I think this might be related: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GloveProblem.html

Comment: @Oleksander: The "published" requirement was not meant to be strict, but meant to separate things like articles and books from, say, cartoon strips (otherwise this thread would be filled with xkcd references.)

Comment: In a similar vein: _Threesomes, Degenerates and Love Triangles_ by Grønlund and Pettie. It is really a serious paper in fine-grained complexity, and the joke in the title is forced.

Answer (score 20):

In fact there is a whole journal that is intended to be funny. The [journal of craptology](http://www.anagram.com/jcrap/). The topics are usually related to cryptography. There are also some sessions videos (!)

One example is the Volume 4 paper of [Cryptography in a Hitchhiker's Universe](http://www.anagram.com/jcrap/Volume_4/Woofbark.pdf) (section 5) is :

> Coming Attractions
>
> If you have enjoyed
>   our feature presentation, you’ll be
>   pleased to hear about upcoming
>   attractions by the same author:
>
> – The
>   cryptanalysis of Human Interactive
>   Protocol Systems. A controversial
>   cryptanalysis of the paper of Shakira
>   [4] which proves that HIPS do, in
>   fact, lie.
>
> – Anti-zero-knowledge. A
>   protocol system which reveals
>   everything that a prover knows except that which the verifier wants to
>   hear. Ad-hoc anti-zero-knowledge
>   protocols have been developed by most
>   customer helpline services.
>
> – Quantum
>   key distribution based on social
>   phenomena. This paper demonstrates how
>   to distribute keys using quantum
>   techniques but without using quantum
>   objects. Instead of using quantum
>   objects, the protocol instead uses the
>   uncertainty that any man has about whether
>   his first evening out with a woman counts as a date or not to transmit the keys.

Answer (score 18):

[Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics), by Ronald Graham, Donald Knuth, and Oren Patashnik.

An amazing book with lots of funny side notes. :) (See also [DEK](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/)'s [GKP](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/gkp.html) page.)

Comment: The side notes are indeed funny, but the book is "just enjoyable" -- granted, not everyone can write an enjoyable book ;-) Anyway, I don't know whether it qualifies as a funny work, but you get my vote because I like the book so much.

Comment: This is my favorite book. I am amazed more authors haven't followed their format.

Answer (score 17):

I would recommend the processings of FUN: the International Conference on Fun With Algorithms.

I must say that "The hardness of the Lemmings game, or Oh no, more NP-completeness proofs" by Graham Cormode is one of my favorite.

Comment: I just found the 2007 FUN proceedings at Powell's books last week - I wholeheartedly second this recommendation! Some great results on pessimal sorting and worst-possible paging algorithms.

Answer (score 16):

Don Knuth's [A
terminological proposal](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1811129.1811130). SIGACT News, 6(1), 1974.  [Mentioned](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2010/11/by-any-other-name-would-be-just-as-hard.html) on The Complexity Blog. This is apparently where we got the terms "NP-complete" and "NP-hard."

One of my favorite's from this piece is Albert Meyer's suggestion that what we now call NP-hard problems be called Hard-as-Satisfiability, or hard-as-S for short.

Answer (score 14):

Mihai Patrascu and Liam Roditty's paper on "[Distance Oracles Beyond the Thorup–Zwick Bound](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/balls/paper.pdf)" was initially titled "[How to grow your balls](http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/balls/talk.pdf)" on Mihai's homepage :-)

Comment: He also changed the presentation name during the FOCS 2010 talk... that was funny

Answer (score 14):

Check out the figure that accompanies Adam Kalai's 1 page SODA paper, "Generating Random Factored Numbers, Easily": [link](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~kalai/papers/old_papers/factorsoda.pdf)

Answer (score 12):

A. Broder, J. Stolfi "[Pessimal algorithms and simplexity analysis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.116.9158)", ACM SIGACT News 16(3), Fall 1984.

The paper introduces "an entirely new branch of Computer Science, the design and analysis of reluctant algorithms. Intuitively, a reluctant algorithm for a problem P is one which wastes time in a way that is suﬃciently contrived to fool a naive observer."

Answer (score 9):

Lamport's [**Part Time Parliament**](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-paxos.pdf) made a breakthrough in distributed computing, but the paper was so (purposely!) obfuscated that people couldn't understand it -- as far as I know, it took him around 10 years to get it published (past editors) in its obfuscated form.  Eventually Lamport followed up with [Paxos Made Simple](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/paxos-simple.pdf), which had the following abstract: "*The Paxos algorithm, when presented in plain English, is very simple*."

Answer (score 9):

The Association for Computational Heresy at CMU has a number of these, which are presented at the annual [SIGBOVIK](http://sigbovik.org/) conference (next held 04/01/2011). My personal favorite is :

A theft-based approach to 3d object acquisition.

Answer (score 8):

In the same spirit as Murilo da Silva's post, I cannot resist posting this excerpt from Goupil and Schaefer's ["Factoring N-Cycles and Counting Maps of Given Genus"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/eujc.1998.0215):

> After this proof, we kindly encourage the reader to pause and enjoy a lighter activity such
>   as bird watching or gardening before pursuing the reading.

Answer (score 7):

["Refinement in State-Based Formalism"](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-TN-1996-001.pdf) by Lamport.

> A friend of ours, who was a brilliant mathematician, has been hospitalized because of long-term abuse of hallucinogenic drugs. We decide to give him a digital clock for his room. However, his doctor suggests that the hour and minute displays together might be too confusing. So, we put tape over the minute display, turning our gift into a digital hour clock.

Answer (score 7):

I just discovered ["A letter from the frustrated author of a journal paper"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0164-1212%2800%2900020-0). Nice read ;-)

Comment: I have heard too much about these processes to reject the letter immediately as satire. I wonder if it is, though. Otherwise, I'm scared.

Answer (score 6):

[Mick gets some (the odds are on his side)](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/SFCS.1992.267789) by <strike>Reed</strike> Chvatal and <strike>Chvatal</strike> Reed (FOCS 1992), on satisfaction (aka satisfiability).

Comment: Your author ordering here is wrong! Btw, more on [author ordering](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17908/author-ordering-in-tcs-papers).

Answer (score 6):

On another topic ([How do I referee a paper?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1893/873)), I found the following paper:

Graham Cormode. 2009. How NOT to review a paper: the tools and techniques of the adversarial reviewer. *SIGMOD Rec*. 37, 4 (March 2009), 100-104. DOI=10.1145/1519103.1519122 http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1519103.1519122

I had a lot of fun reading this paper ;)

Answer (score 6):

I came across the ["Complexity Theory Newsflash"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=571629&CFID=87351920&CFTOKEN=55770769) at some point, and thought it was pretty funny.

Comment: Nice!  Working through these also serves as a nice refresher in some of the classic complexity results.

Answer (score 6):

[How much damage could be caused by a peer reviewer having a bad day?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/misc/reject.pdf)
Hilarious fictional reviews of famous old CS papers.

Comment: The link is dead and I couldn't find the paper using a quick google search. Could you maybe reupload it somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Recent funny titles:

- A. Kehagias, P. Pralat, 
  *Some remarks on cops and drunk robbers*, 
  Theoretical Computer Science 463 (2012) 133-147, 
  [DOI](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439751200789X)
- A. Kehagias, D. Mitsche, P. Pralatb, 
  *Cops and invisible Robbers: The cost of drunkenness*, 
  Theoretical Computer Science (2013), 
  [in Press](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397513001096)
- Natasha Komarov, Peter Winkle, 
  *Capturing the Drunk Robber on a Graph*, May 2013, [arXiv:1305.4559](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4559)

Answer (score 5):

[The Alice and Bob After Dinner Speech](http://downlode.org/Etext/alicebob.html) by John Gordon.

Nice light-hearted talk on coding theory.

Comment: It's entertaining how much of what he claims his pocket calculator could do is actually now possible on a modern smartphone. No 3D holographic displays yet, and you might be hard-pressed to find a compiler from ADA to Android, but apart from that...

Answer (score 5):

Bruce Reed, [Mangoes and Blueberries](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004930050056), Combinatorica 19 (1999) 267-296 .

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think now of a funny paper, but I do remember of a "normal" paper that had a funny line in it. It was in fact the very first sentence in Section 1. The authors began the paper with:

***"Contrary to our usual practice, we feel obliged to begin this paper with
a few definitions". So let G..."***

The title of the paper is "`$beta$`-perfect graphs", by Markossian, Gasparian and
Reed in 1996. It called my attention because it is in fact a key paper 
on perfect graph theory, where it is defined the class of beta-perfect graphs, a class 
that is in a way analogous to the perfect graphs (beta-perfect graphs being
a subclass of EVEN-hole-free graphs, whereas perfect graphs are a subclass of
ODD-hole-free graphs.

Comment: Also known as "Since this is a theory talk, I would start by defining the problem I am talking about..."

Answer (score 4):

As far as a funny title: "How to play a coloring game against a color-blind adversary"

http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1137865

Answer (score 4):

How about [Scott is not always sober](http://www.springerlink.com/content/9256577622j64575/)?

Answer (score 4):

"Busy beavers gone wild" by Grégory Lafitte, EPTCS 1, 2009, pp. 123-129
[arXiv:0906.3257v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3257v1)

Answer (score 3):

Lambda the Ultimate brought to my attention the whitepaper on [Phosphorous, the Popular Lisp](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3488), which if "Popular Lisp" didn't tip you off, is satirical ^_-

Answer (score 3):

The [winner](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=398) of the 2007 Aaronson/Gasarch Complexity Theme Song Contest is amazing!
Download the [mp3](http://www.scottaaronson.com/jdtheory.mp3) and its [lyrics](http://www.scottaaronson.com/jdtheory.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Without doubt, the most humorous mathematical writing award should go to Zeilberger. Considering that he writes about areas close to TCS and his views of TCS are very favorable makes his writings even more fun to read.

Comment: agreed! great sense of humor, sometimes poking fun even at TCS community itself & its conventions, eg crediting imaginary pseudonymous coauthor "Shalosh B. Ekhad". see eg his [P=NP crank paper april fool spoof/hoax](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9952/doron-zeilbergers-p-np-computer-proof)

Answer (score 2):

[Jaywalking your Dog - Computing the Fréchet Distance with Shortcuts](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1720) by Anne Driemel and Sariel Har-Peled at SODA 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on László Babai's homepage:

"Enjoy a fun paper from 1990 that is only partly technical and tells a fable about Merlin, Arthur, competition, and the ethics of mathematical communication: 
[E-mail and the Unexpected Power of Interaction](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/papers/email90.pdf)"

Answer (score 2):

[On the hardness of losing weight](http://www.cs.bme.hu/~dmarx/papers/krokhin-marx-losing-weight-talg.pdf) by Dániel Marx and Andrei Krokhin. 
ACM Transactions on Algorithms, 8(2):19, 2012. Despite the funny title, the paper is serious.

Answer (score 1):

This paper is not a humorous theory paper, but it is a really humorous paper by a theoretician, about dangers of being sloppy about punctuation.

For example, in bibliography, he spelled his own name as:

J. Dullman

(As most reader know, Ullman's middle initial is D.)

I can't recall the full details (issue, year #, page), but it appeared in SIGACT newsletter in late 80's.

Answer (score 1):

"Why ordinals are good for you" by I. Lepper and G. Moser. The paper itself is not intended to be humorous but it contains some funny quotes. I would be curious to see a similar introductory paper to the surreal numbers, a superclass of the ordinals introduced by J.H. Conway.

Answer (score 1):

When I read this question, I immediately expected to see a mention of Connor McBride's ["Kleisli Arrows of Outrageous Fortune"](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf).  It begins with the greatest series of puns I've seen in any CS paper.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to use mixed integer linear programming to assist you playing Pokemon Go?

[Gotta (efficiently) catch them all: Pokémon GO meets Orienteering Problems](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2017.08.012)

> In this paper, a new routing problem, referred to as the Generalized Clustered Orienteering Problem (GCOP), is studied. The problem is motivated by the mobile phone game Pokémon GO, an augmented reality game for mobile devices (...)

---

> The computational performance of the proposed approaches is assessed in an extensive computational study, using real-world instances that combine crowd-sourced data associated with the Pokémon GO game with street maps of three European cities (...)

Answer (score 0):

blog posts ok? its "published" in a sense & blogs are increasingly mainstream and many now written by senior/elite researchers. just recently ran across this old, imaginative entry from last April 1 from the Algorithmic Game Theory Blog, with clever resemblance to real events. see comments for colorful feedback. eg MacArthur fellow Terence Tao comments

> A fantastic achievement! Now that Reimann’s hypothesis is settled, one can hope that the closely related Riemann’s hypothesis will fall next…

[Automatic proof for Reimanns hypothesis](http://agtb.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/automatic-proof-for-reimanns-hypothesis/)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a paper, but I think in the spirit of your question you'll appreciate [JofUR](http://www.universalrejection.org/): Journal of Universal Rejection.

Their website include numerous reasons why you should submit there, detailed instructions for authors, and interesting proceedings.